# The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records, but credentials was already set

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

Through boto3 library, I uploaded and downloaded file from AWS s3 **successfully**.
But after few hours, it shows InvalidAccessKeyId suddenly for the same code.

What I have done:

- `set ~/.aws/credentials`
- `Set environment variables AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

I tried the following solutions, but the error still heppens.

[adding quotes on config values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51920001/amazon-s3-to-store-wagtail-media-files-server-500-error-on-heroku-only)

[ref2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39051477/the-aws-access-key-id-does-not-exist-in-our-records)

Do I miss anything? Thanks for your help.

Comment: From where did you obtain the credentials? Are they associated with an IAM user, or were they generated as _temporary credentials_?

Comment: Are you running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance? If so, is there an IAM Role attached to the instance?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The credentials is associated with an IAM user. I believe it's not a temporary credential according to an article on SO (but I cannot found it right now), which tells AKIA prefix isn't and mine is also AKIA prefix. I an running the code on local (dev) and heroku (production) separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this [article](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=771815) for the same issue.
Amazon suggests to generate new key, and I did.
Then it works, but we don't know the root cause.
Suggest to do so for saving a lot of time when having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` there is no need to set environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` & `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`.

Environment variables are valid only for a session.

If you are using boto3, you can specify the credentials while creating client itself.

The best way to configure AWS credential is to install the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) and run `aws configure` from the bash console:

```
~/.aws/credentials format

[default]
aws_access_key_id = ***********
aws_secret_access_key = ************
```

Comment: Thank you, and that's what I did. I run `aws configure` at the first. And I set environment variables for trouble shooting.

Comment: It should work if you have the correct credentials in "aws configure". Please check your system date, time and time-zone.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to configure both `.aws/credentials` *AND* environment variables.

From [Credentials — Boto 3 documentation](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html):

> The order in which Boto3 searches for credentials is:

- Passing credentials as parameters in the `boto.client()` method
- Passing credentials as parameters when creating a Session object
- Environment variables
- Shared credential file (`~/.aws/credentials`)
- AWS config file (`~/.aws/config`)
- Assume Role provider
- Boto2 config file (`/etc/boto.cfg` and `~/.boto`)
- Instance metadata service on an Amazon EC2 instance that has an IAM role configured.

The fact that your credentials stopped working after a period of time suggests that they were *temporary credentials* created via the [AWS Security Token Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), with an expiry time.